# How to return multiple results while executing multiple queries?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am executing 4 queries inside a function. How I can return those 4 results at a time so that I can use all 4 results while calling the function? Should I create an array and store all of the results inside that array? I tried to return the result one by one but after calling `return` command, function exits from that point. Is there any way to return each of the query result individually?  Here's my code:

```
function select_all_category_name() {
        require 'admin/db_connect.php'; 
        $sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_category WHERE publication_status=1 AND deletion_status=1";

        if (mysqli_query($db_connect, $sql)) {

            $sql1="SELECT * FROM tbl_category WHERE publication_status=1 AND deletion_status=1 AND mpid='' AND spid='' AND pid=''";
            $sql2="SELECT * FROM tbl_category WHERE publication_status=1 AND deletion_status=1 AND mpid!='' AND spid='' AND pid=''";
            $sql3="SELECT * FROM tbl_category WHERE publication_status=1 AND deletion_status=1 AND mpid!='' AND spid!='' AND pid=''";
            $sql4="SELECT * FROM tbl_category WHERE publication_status=1 AND deletion_status=1 AND mpid!='' AND spid!='' AND pid!=''";
            $query_result1=mysqli_query($db_connect, $sql1);
            $query_result2=mysqli_query($db_connect, $sql2);
            $query_result3=mysqli_query($db_connect, $sql3);
            $query_result4=mysqli_query($db_connect, $sql4);


        } else {
            die("Query Problem". mysqli_error($db_connect));
        }
    }
```

`db_connect.php` file contains the connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this ?

```
function select_all_category_name() {
    require 'admin/db_connect.php'; 
    $sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_category WHERE publication_status=1 AND deletion_status=1";

    if (mysqli_query($db_connect, $sql)) {

        $sql1="SELECT * FROM tbl_category WHERE publication_status=1 AND deletion_status=1 AND mpid='' AND spid='' AND pid=''";
        $sql2="SELECT * FROM tbl_category WHERE publication_status=1 AND deletion_status=1 AND mpid!='' AND spid='' AND pid=''";
        $sql3="SELECT * FROM tbl_category WHERE publication_status=1 AND deletion_status=1 AND mpid!='' AND spid!='' AND pid=''";
        $sql4="SELECT * FROM tbl_category WHERE publication_status=1 AND deletion_status=1 AND mpid!='' AND spid!='' AND pid!=''";

        $result_array = array(
            "query_result1" => mysqli_query($db_connect, $sql1),
            "query_result2" => mysqli_query($db_connect, $sql2),
            "query_result3" => mysqli_query($db_connect, $sql3),
            "query_result4" => mysqli_query($db_connect, $sql4)
        );

     return $result_array;
    } else {
        die("Query Problem". mysqli_error($db_connect));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use arrays:

```
function select_all_category_name() {
    require 'admin/db_connect.php'; 
    $sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_category WHERE publication_status=1 AND deletion_status=1";

    if (mysqli_query($db_connect, $sql)) {
        $ret = [
             "{$sql} AND mpid ='' AND spid ='' AND pid =''",
             "{$sql} AND mpid!='' AND spid ='' AND pid =''",
             "{$sql} AND mpid!='' AND spid!='' AND pid =''",
             "{$sql} AND mpid!='' AND spid!='' AND pid!=''",
        ];
        foreach ($ret as $i => $sqlx) {
            $ret[$i] = mysqli_query($db_connect, $sqlx);
        };
        return $ret;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Or you can use a single query for the *whole function* (it will return an empty array if nothing is found):

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN mpid='' AND spid='' AND pid='' THEN 0,
        WHEN mpid!='' AND spid='' AND pid='' THEN 1,
        WHEN mpid!='' AND spid!='' AND pid='' THEN 2,
        WHEN mpid!='' AND spid!='' AND pid!='' THEN 3
        ELSE -1
    END AS idx,
    *
FROM tbl_category 
WHERE publication_status=1 AND deletion_status=1
HAVING idx != -1
```

Answer (score 0):

A function can only 'return' one value. So you cannot return all 4 query results separately. Array is your only option.